# Tomcat with execjs rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby

I have a jruby app deployed onto tomcat and it will not pickup nodejs for a javascript runtime. Node is installed and the `node` command executes properly under the tomcat6 user.

log dump
https://gist.github.com/3192173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use native c extensions with jRuby.

For jRuby, use [therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino) instead.

The issue is documented & discussed [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/2963). For a list of supported runtimes see the [execjs docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/sstephenson/execjs/frames).

You can however setup nodejs for local development if you use MRI as the local interpreter instead of jRuby on the JVM.